# Close a Word document using CMD Command line

Tags: command-line, cmd

I had just tried opening a Microsoft Word document using command line but I don't know how to close it from the command line.

How can I close a Word document each time I execute a command line?

Comment: Have a look here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/deea382d-57a0-4f20-8208-bae6270981e2/how-do-you-close-word-2007-from-the-command-line?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy and see if it helps.

Comment: Why did you edit Alvaro Gonzales? Closing instance of word will kill other open word documents. What I want to know if there are any chances that a command line can close a specific word document file.

Comment: I assumed you were talking about Microsoft Word program from Microsoft Office. Do you want to close the document no matter what program it's used? If it opens with Microsoft Wordpad or LibreOffice Writer, close those instead? *BTW, my name is Gonzalez, not Gonzales* ;-)

Comment: @Alvaro, Yes I want to close a Microsoft Word document from MS Office. For example: I open doc1.docx using CMD, then I want to close doc1.docx using CMD command line. Is there a way? :P

Comment: So my edit was pertinent after all?

Comment: Ohhh, sorry I thought your edit was pertaining to WINWORD*32.exe  where it can handle multiple task applications of Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

Start your instance of Word with the following command to capture the PID for the specific instance opened by your script:

`for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in (' wmic process call create "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" ^| find "ProcessId" ') do set PID=%%a`

*Note I'm using x86 Office 2016 so adjust your path to Word accordingly.*

You can then kill off the instance of Word opened by your script with `taskkill /PID %%a`

Comment: Thanks rawns, i am also aware of taskkill. But will this kill other opened word documents? I just want to close a specific word file. Is there a way?

Comment: How to do the same in Mac OSX

Comment: Will this save the document?